# Implementing single pass algorithm to find column to column inclusion by using min heap data structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, heap

I am trying to implement the following algorithm in Python, and though I have successfully achieved the same result, my processing time is really slow. The author of this algorithm claims that his performance is at least multifolds faster than what I experience.

Some details on the databases I process:
- no of tables: 200
- total size: 3GB

```
Input: attributes: set of attribute objects with their sorted values and their
       respective refs sets (the IND candidates)

Output: Set of satisfied INDs.

Min-Heap heap := new Min-Heap( attributes )
while heap != ∅ do
    //getattributes with equal min.value
    att := heap.removeMinAttributes()
    foreach A ∈ att do
        // update list A.refs
        A.refs := A.refs ∩ att
        // process next value
        if A has next value then
            A.moveCursor()
            heap.add(A)
        else
            foreach B ∈ A.refs do
                INDs := INDs ∪ { A ⊆ B }
    return INDs
```

Definitions:
- `attributes`: columns where only unique values are kept and they are sorted in ascending order
- `att`: all columns where they have the same minimum values in the heap
- `IND`: column pair, for example, column A and column B, where all values in column A are covered in column B
- `A.refs`: list of all columns that contain values of column A

Data structure of the heap should look something like:

```
A    B    C
1    1
3         3
5    5    5
          7
```

My current data structure looks like

```
    A    B    C
1   1    1    nan
3   3    nan  3
5   5    5    5
7   nan  nan  7
```

So then, my implementation of the algorithm is that for each index of the dataframe, get column names that have that value.

Is that the right way to implement the `min heap`? If not, how should I do it?

**EDIT**
Below is my code for the implementation

```
ind_dict = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
            'B': ['A', 'C'],
            'C': ['A', 'B']}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 3, 5, np.nan],
                               'B': [1, np.nan, 5, np.nan],
                               'C': [np.nan, 3, 5, 7]},
                         index=[1, 3, 5, 7])


def algorithm(self, dataframe, ind_dict):
    # for each cursor value, get all columns that has it
    for cursor, i in zip(dataframe.index, range(0, len(dataframe.index))):

        # columns that contain the current cursor value
        column_containing_cursor = [i for i, x in enumerate(dataframe.iloc[i]) if x == cursor]

        atts = [list(dataframe.iloc[i].index)[n] for n in column_containing_cursor]

        # for each column in ind_dict.keys(), intersect its values with atts to get the remaining att.refs
        # if the current column value is null, then do nothing
        for key in ind_dict.keys():
            column_val = dataframe.loc[cursor, key]

            if (column_val == column_val) & (column_val != ''):
                ind_dict[key] = list(set(ind_dict[key]).intersection(atts))
```

Comment: We can't see your implementation... also, is this pandas? You could have expensive copies going on but, again, we can't see the implementation in Python.

Comment: apologies, i will include some codes now in there. but to answer your question now, yes it is `pandas` dataframe for my implementation

Comment: have added my implementation code currently @roganjosh

Answer (score 0):

After revisiting the paper and spending some time reviewing `heap` theory, I finally figured out how to implement it using the `heapq` library.

The `data frame` I showed in my question above is not needed anymore, which means I have saved time and space by eliminating the need to merge all the columns into a single `data frame` (merging columns into a single `data frame` took a long time due to the size).

Below is the implementation code.

Essentially, all the values from all the columns are stored in a `tuple` structure and pushed into the `min heap`. We first pop the smallest element based on the value, and then iterate for all tuples that have the same value.

When the iteration finishes, we will get the `att` (all columns) that have the current smallest value. Then, we update the `ind_dict` and move on to the next smallest value until the `min heap` is empty.

```
import heapq

col_vals = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
            'B': [2, 4],
            'C': [1, 2, 4, 5]}

ind_dict = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
            'B': ['A', 'C'],
            'C': ['A', 'B']}

min_heap = []

for column in col_vals:
    vals = col_vals[column]

    for val in vals:
        tup = (val, column)
        heapq.heappush(min_heap, tup)

while min_heap:
    # get the smallest value in the heap
    att = []

    current_smallest, var = heapq.heappop(min_heap)
    att.append(var)

    # pop all the elements and put them in a list where value is equal to current smallest value
    while min_heap and min_heap[0][0] == current_smallest:
        next_var = heapq.heappop(min_heap)[-1]
        att.append(next_var)

    # update ind att.refs
    for a in att:
        ind_dict[a] = list(set(ind_dict[a]).intersection(att))
```